# ORA-39126 Worker unexpected fatal error in KUPW$WORKER.PUT_DDL [FUNCTION:"ABC"."GETSYSDATE"]

Tags: oracle, import, oracle10g, impdp

we have a development server and we are importing database from the production server using datapump impdp, but it terminates with ORA-39126 Worker unexpected fatal error in  KUPW$WORKER.PUT_DDL [FUNCTION:"ABC"."GETSYSDATE"]. we had a power failure and I think the db crashed. But similar situations had taken place before and we are using the method we used to do to up our development server db. Please help anyone...??[image]

Comment: before it (import) used to work seamlessly, this time it is not...